# Parse the place field in Twitter Tweets in Python

Tags: python, tweets

I am trying to parse the place field in Twitter Tweets. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets.

In particular I want to extract the country code from country_code, and the state from the full_name field respectively.

I want to use the country_code as `if entry['place']['country_code'] ...` and `entry['full_name']['state']`

I am totally new to Python. I am using:

```
for jsonstring in fp:
    entry = json.loads(jsonstring)
```

to read in tweet from file.

I don't know the correct syntax passed a simple key, value dictionary, nor how to retrieve the state from the full name field.

Once I get some help I will know how to do python dictionaries.

thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: Is your question "How do I get the twitter api response into a dictionary?"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help: (A link to python-twitter API)
https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/